# Android emulator does not run but Gradle builds successfully

Tags: android

I am new to `Android Studio` and I am facing this weird kind of behavior.

I have built a raw project in `Android Studio` and I have configured `Andriod AVD`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Gradle builds successfully though. It shows `waiting for the device to come online`.

[image]

[image]

I am using a `Mac`.

[image]

Comment: You need to run your AVD. Open AVD and Start the created emulator.

Comment: It will take time to `the device to come online`. or you can first you start emulator and when emulator started then try to run your app..

Comment: Be sure you're actually deploying the app, and not just building it. Hit the play button instead of the hammer.

Comment: When I open the AVD manager and click the green run button it says starting AVD but then nothing happens. Please see the screenshot

Comment: It will take some time to load for the first time.

Comment: You can see this icon in Dock http://imgur.com/uHK7vQ5

Comment: @AjithPandian I can't see the same. It has been more than 5 minutes.

Comment: Can you try this via terminal? https://gist.github.com/Ajith-Pandian/04865ba333a98531349c976f16769033

Comment: Check out Genymotion. This emulator is much faster . You can install this free trial software, create an emulator and run your application. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWZ2rVFOQWw

Comment: @AjithPandian It throws error. PANIC: Unknown AVD name [Nexus_5X_API_23], use -list-avds to see valid list.
HOME is defined but there is no file Nexus_5X_API_23.ini in $HOME/.android/avd
(Note: Directories are searched in the order $ANDROID_AVD_HOME, $ANDROID_SDK_HOME/avd and $HOME/.android/avd)

Comment: You need to specify you AVD name instead of "Nexus_5X_API_23"

Comment: Use the name from here http://imgur.com/8TRRVwV

Answer (score 0):

You can run on real device to check what happen of you can down load genymotion and run your application on that virutal machine